# How to Dynamically create a CSS class using AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, class, dynamically-generated

I have an Angular JS web site where I am using data from an API that I want to use to dynamically create a CSS class.  This CSS class will then format other data from the API being displayed in an Angular JS page.

For example, is there a way for Angular JS $scope data to be created in the Controller while processing the API data and then on the corresponding .html view, use this $scope data to dynamically create a CSS class ... By the way, $scope data cannot be used inside the HTML 'STYLE' tag, because the bracket characters ('{' and '}') are treated as 'STYLE' characters, so it does not allow '{{' and '}}' to expand the value of a $scope variable.

**EDIT:** The above comments were based on using the Visual Studio 2013 IDE where the Angular syntax is shown as an Error in the VS IDE.  Using this syntax (as shown below by Valentyn) allows a CSS class to define dynamic attributes and works great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `{{` and `}}` inside of `<style>`:

```css
<style>
      .p { background-color: {{name}}; }
</style>
```

Try:
http://plnkr.co/edit/MMgRJP0fFCowE1rxcULM?p=preview

Comment: Thanks ... I am using Visual Studio 2013 and this syntax shows an error, so I did not think it would work.  When I ran the page with my $scope variables, it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) for this:

```html
<element ng-style="function_result() or expression"></element>
```