# How to replace css class value using angularjs values?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a problem now to make my css values dynamic. I have this kind of code but not working

```
<style>
    .panel-primary {
         background-color:{{myColorPanel}}
    }
</style>
```

I've seen this post from this link

[How to Dynamically create a CSS class using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990055/how-to-dynamically-create-a-css-class-using-angularjs)

i don't know what is my mistakes there that it didn't work.

Anyone have an alternative solution to my problem.

I just want to make bootstrap panel to be customized in colors and i don't want to put `ng-class` or `ng-style` in every panel i used coz it is so many.

Anyone have an idea please let me know.

**Full Code**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="Aptus">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" charset="utf-8">
    <title>Centralized Test</title>
    <!--<link href="http://cdn.dbtc.sdb.ph/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <link href="contents/css/angucomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="contents/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="contents/css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="contents/css/loading-bar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="contents/css/loading-bar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="contents/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="contents/css/cropper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/myStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="contents/css/elusive-webfont.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="contents/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="contents/css/angular-chart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Scripts/ckeditor/contents.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Contents/css/colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        .ng-ckeditor {
            border: 0;
        }

        body {
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        #sidebar-dropdown {
            color: #9a96a1 !important;
        }

        .form-control {
            border-radius: 0 !important;
        }

        .modal .modal-body {
            max-height: 450px !important;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        @media (max-width:767px) {
            .small-width-hidden {
                display: none;
            }
        }

        @media screen {
            footer {
                display: none;
            }
        }

        @media print {
            .progress {
                background-color: #F5F5F5 !important;
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#F5F5F5', endColorstr='#F5F5F5')" !important;
            }

            .progress-bar-success {
                display: block !important;
                background-color: #198718 !important;
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#198718', endColorstr='#198718')" !important;
            }

            .progress-bar-info {
                display: block !important;
                background-color: #5BC0DE !important;
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#5BC0DE', endColorstr='#5BC0DE')" !important;
            }

            .progress, .progress > .progress-bar {
                display: block !important;
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
                box-shadow: inset 0 0 !important;
                -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 !important;
            }

            .not-printable {
                display: none;
            }

            .additional {
                display: inline-block !important;
            }

            .printable {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                padding: 10px;
            }

            .small-font {
                font-size: 8pt !important;
            }

            .small-padding > tbody > tr > td {
                padding-top: 1px !important;
                padding-bottom: 1px !important;
                margin: 1px !important;
            }

            .small-padding > tbody > tr > th {
                padding-top: 1px !important;
                padding-bottom: 1px !important;
                margin: 1px !important;
            }

            .small-padding > table {
                padding: 1px !important;
            }

            .small-font > span {
                font-size: 6pt !important;
            }

            footer {
                position: fixed !important;
                bottom: 0 !important;
            }

            @page {
                size: auto;
                margin: 5mm;
            }
        }

        #CriteriaTable > tr > th {
            padding-top: 0px !important;
            padding-bottom: 0px !important;
        }

        .dashboardsubmenu {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

        .tab-content {
            border-right: solid 1px #ddd;
            border-left: solid 1px #ddd;
            border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;
        }

        #icon-tab > li > a {
            border-radius: 0 !important;
        }

        #loading-bar-spinner .spinner-icon {
            width: 14px;
            height: 14px;
            border: solid 2px transparent;
            border-top-color: red;
            border-left-color: red;
            border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-animation: loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
            -moz-animation: loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
            -ms-animation: loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
            -o-animation: loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
            animation: loading-bar-spinner 400ms linear infinite;
        }

        #loading-bar .bar {
            background: red;
        }

        #loading-bar .peg {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100%;
            box-shadow: 0 0 1px red, 0 0 1px red;
            opacity: 1.0;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg) translate(0px, -4px);
            -moz-transform: rotate(3deg) translate(0px, -4px);
            -ms-transform: rotate(3deg) translate(0px, -4px);
            -o-transform: rotate(3deg) translate(0px, -4px);
            transform: rotate(3deg) translate(0px, -4px);
        }

        /************For Angular-Modal****************/
        @media (max-width:530px) {
            .message {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }
        /*******************************************/
        a:not(:hover) {
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }

        .modal-content {
            border-radius: 0;
        }

        .go-top {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 1em;
            left: 1em;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 1em;
            display: none;
        }

            .go-top:hover {
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
                color: white;
            }

        .math-tex {
            font-size: 20px !important;
        }

        table.floatThead-table {
            border-top: none;
            border-bottom: none;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
        extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
        jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
        tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
        processEscapes: true
        }
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script><!---->
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
      </script>-->
</head>
<body data-ng-cloak="" data-ng-controller="indexController">
    <style>
        .panel-primary {
            background-color:{{myColorPanel}}
        }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="sidebar-wrapper not-printable">
                    <div class="sidebar not-printable" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                        <a href="#" class="logo">Centralized Test</a>
                        <div class="user-panel">
                            <div class="pull-left image">
                                <img src="Contents/images/photo.png" class="circular" alt="User Image" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="pull-left info">
                                <p>Hello {{lastName}}</p>

                                <a class="cursor-pointer" data-ng-click="logOut()">Log Out</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                            <li><a class="cursor-pointer">Dashboard</a></li>
                            <li id="sidebar-dropdown" data-ng-repeat="mod in modulesData | filter:{userRoleName:currentRole || ''}" data-ng-class="{'active' : activeModule == mod.moduleId}">
                                <a href="{{mod.moduleUrl}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{mod.moduleId}}" data-ng-click="setCurrentModule(mod);SetActiveModule(mod.moduleId)">
                                    <span class="pull-right"><span class="caret" data-ng-show="mod.moduleUrl == '#' || mod.moduleUrl == ''"></span></span><i class="{{mod.iconUrl}}"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>{{mod.moduleName}}</span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="collapse dashboardsubmenu" id="{{mod.moduleId}}" style="list-style-type: none">
                                    <li class="list-group-item no-border" data-ng-repeat="sub in mod.subModule | filter:{userRoleName:currentRole || ''}"><a href="{{sub.moduleUrl}}" data-ng-click="setCurrentModule(sub)"><i class="{{sub.iconUrl}}"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>{{sub.moduleName}}</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="container not-printable">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="header">
                                    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navigation" role="navigation">

                                        <a class="navbar-toggle navbar-left cursor-pointer" role="button" id="toggle-button">
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="navbar-left">
                                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                                <li><a class="cursor-pointer" href="#/home" data-ng-click="setCurrentModule('Dashboard')" style="color:white !important"><span class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></span></a></li>
                                                <li class="dropdown" data-ng-show="iTestRoles.length>0">
                                                    <a class="cursor-pointer dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown-menu" data-target="#Roles">{{currentRole}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="Roles">
                                                        <li data-ng-repeat="data in iTestRoles"><a class="cursor-pointer" data-ng-click="SetiTestRole(data.userRoleName,data.userRoleId)">{{data.userRoleName}}</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="dropdown" data-ng-show="iTestSubjectGrade.length>0">
                                                    <a class="cursor-pointer dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown-menu" data-target="#SubGrade">{{subject}} {{grade}}<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="SubGrade">
                                                        <li data-ng-repeat="data in iTestSubjectGrade"><a class="cursor-pointer" data-ng-click="SetiTestSubGrade(data.subject,data.grade,data.subjectCode,data.gradeID)">{{data.subject}} {{data.grade}}</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="navbar-right right-nav">
                                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                                <li class="dropdown">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle cursor-pointer" data-toggle="dropdown-menu" data-target="ProfileMenu">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;{{firstName
                                                        }} {{middleInitial}} {{lastName}} <span class="caret"></span>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="ProfileMenu">
                                                        <!-- User image -->
                                                        <li class="user-header bg-light-green">
                                                            <img src="Contents/images/photo.png" class="circular" alt="User Image" />
                                                            <p>
                                                                {{firstName}} {{middleInitial}} {{lastName}}
                                                                <!--- {{userRole}}-->
                                                                <small></small>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <!-- Menu Body -->
                                                        <li class="user-body">
                                                            <!-- <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                                                        <a href="#">Followers</a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                                                        <a href="#">Sales</a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                                                        <a href="#">Friends</a>
                                                                    </div>-->
                                                        </li>
                                                        <!-- Menu Footer-->
                                                        <li class="user-footer">
                                                            <div class="pull-left">
                                                                <a class="btn btn-default btn-flat cursor-pointer">Profile</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="pull-right">
                                                                <a class="btn btn-default btn-flat cursor-pointer" data-ng-click="logOut()">Sign out</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </nav>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row not-printable" id="content-title">
                                <h3>{{currentModule.moduleDescription}}</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" id="content">
                                <div data-ng-view="" class="printable">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="go-top text-center not-printable">
            <span class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up not-printable" style="font-size:32px"></span><br />
            <span class="not-printable">Go to Top</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="icon" class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content" style="border-radius:0">
                <div class="modal-header" style="border-radius:0;background-color:#3c8dbc">
                    <label class="modal-title" style="color:white">Icons</label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs cursor-pointer" role="tablist" id="icon-tab">
                        <li class="active"><a class="cursor-pointer" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#glyphicons">Glyphicons</a></li>
                        <li><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#font-awesome">Font-Awesome</a></li>
                        <li><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#elusive">Elusive-Icon</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="glyphicons">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 cursor-pointer" data-ng-repeat="glyph in ModuleIcons.GlyphIcons" style="padding:10px"><span class="{{glyph.Name}}"></span></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="font-awesome">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 cursor-pointer" data-ng-repeat="awesome in ModuleIcons.FontAwesome" style="padding:10px"><span class="{{awesome.Name}}"></span></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="elusive">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 cursor-pointer" data-ng-repeat="elusive in ModuleIcons.ElusiveIcon" style="padding:10px"><span class="{{elusive.Name}}"></span></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" style="border-radius:0">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="Submit(classes,enrollCodes)">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="warning-dialog.html">
        <div class="modal-header" style="border-radius:0">
            <h4 style="font-weight:bolder" class="text-center">You're Idle. Do Something!</h4>
        </div>
        <div ng-idle-countdown="countdown" ng-init="countdown=10" class="modal-body" style="border-radius:0">
            <progressbar max="10" value="10" animate="false" class="progress-striped active">You'll be logged out in {{countdown}} second(s).</progressbar>
        </div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="timedout-dialog.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>You've Timed Out!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
                You were idle too long. Normally you'd be logged out, but in this demo just do anything and you'll be reset.
            </p>
        </div>
    </script>


    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/loading-bar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-idle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angucomplete-alt.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/cropper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/dashboard.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ng-ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angularjs-unique.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap-colorpicker-module.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Controllers/IndexController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Controllers/loginController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Services/authInterceptorService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Services/authService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Services/HomeService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Filters/Filter.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Controllers/SetupController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Services/SetupService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Directives/Directives.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Controllers/TestController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Services/TestService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Controllers/ITestController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Services/ITestService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Services/SignalRService.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.floatThead.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Controllers/ActivateExamController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Services/ExamActivationService.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#icon-tab a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            $(this).tab('show')
        });
        //$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {
        //    modal_this = this
        //    $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
        //        if (modal_this.$element[0] !== e.target && !modal_this.$element.has(e.target).length
        //        && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select')
        //        && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')) {
        //            modal_this.$element.focus()
        //        }
        //    })
        //};

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Show or hide the sticky footer button
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                    $('.go-top').fadeIn(200);
                } else {
                    $('.go-top').fadeOut(200);
                }
            });

            // Animate the scroll to top
            $('.go-top').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 300);
            })
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `ng-class` instead...

Comment: so it means i will alter every panel that I'm using? no other easier ways?

Comment: that should work. do you see the correct color when you inspect the dom?

Comment: Use this <style>.panel-primary { background-color:{{myColorPanel}} !important; } </style> ... Might be there is overlapping any other class so make this important and then check

Comment: Where have you added the above code?

Comment: `background-color:{{myColorPanel}}` that is the display in the DOM and there is a warning sign invalid property value

Comment: i put that code inside the body..

Comment: set the default value for this scope {{myColorPanel}}

Comment: may be your are missing # sign for hash color that is why there is warning for color property

Comment: let me know if this should work..`$scope.myColorPanel = 'red';` its the code in my controller

Comment: @DatzMe .. Please put your all html and js code here

Comment: its too long.. Still want me to post it here?

Comment: Yes , without this we cannot get your problem

Comment: @DatzMe i have checked your html code . can you please tell me where you are adding this panel-primary class.

Comment: i didn't include controller but this is i think the important part there ` $scope.myColorPanel = 'red';`

Comment: <body data-ng-cloak="" data-ng-controller="indexController">
    <style>
        .panel-primary {
            background-color:{{myColorPanel}}
        }
    </style>

Comment: this is css code ... where are you using this class "panel-primary"

Comment: it is inside the views?i put the container then inside the view is another html do i need to put it also. i tried to make that css in the template html but still not working..

Comment: This could be the issue ... You have put this code in index.html file and you are accessing this class in other views .... can you put this <style>
    .panel-primary {
         background-color:{{myColorPanel}} !important;
    }
</style> code in the views file where you are using this "panel-primary " class and remember set this myColorPanel scope value with there associative controller file.

Comment: i already did but let me try it again and deleting the one in the index and ill let you know what will happen

Comment: still the same dude.. still not showing the `red` in the DOM instead it shows `background-color:{{myColorPanel}} !important` and not invalid

Comment: Did you set the scope again in associative controller ?

Comment: yes i did like this `$scope.myColorPanel='red';`

Comment: did you put this class in ng-class directive or in simple class attribute ?

Comment: but just asking if angularjs is really accepted from the style part?

Comment: nope.. if i put `ng-class` then i put every panel an `ng-class`.. i know it will work if i use `ng-class` but then im trying to make it into 1 simple code with one change and change all the class in the system.

Comment: i mean in your html use this class like this ng-class="panel-primary"

Comment: no its just a class..should make it ng-class?

Comment: Yes please try this also..

Comment: it didn't work dude..

Comment: With the "simple Class attribute" before angular loads your class will literally be "{{myColorPanel}}". While in the ng-class the div won't have a class until angular runs its first digest.

Comment: @DatzMe Use the ng-class like this ... In your view file , ng-class="myColorPanel" and in the controller $scope.myColorPanel = "panel-primary". and $scope.myColorPanelColor = "red". and <style> .panel-primary { background-color:{{myColorPanelColor}} !important; } </style>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I found the real problem. Its the version of the angularjs that i use didn't support angularjs in style. Since it is an existing system, the angularjs used is older version. The version I previously used is `1.2x` then i updated it to newer version (`1.5x`) and all the code I used is now working. Thank a lot for all the effort of you guys. I know its my fault not realized about the version of angularjs but thank you so much.

The solution was changing from old version to newer version.

Answer (score 1):

I've provided a simple example below as to how you can switch classes, not directly modify the classes, however that's not a very typical procedure.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myClass = 'blue'
}
```

```css
.blue { color: blue }
.red { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h2 ng-class="myClass" ng-click="myClass = myClass == 'blue' ? 'red' : 'blue'">Click Me!</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: The color should be come from my database. There is no problem with `ng-class` and `ng-style` but the thing is that the system is existing and a lots of panel used. So im trying not to make a lot of changes by making a class with a value so that all the panel will just change.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
      angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("myController",function($scope){
      $scope.name="sagar";
        $scope.myColorPanel ="green";
        $scope.colorChange=function(color){
         $scope.myColorPanel =color;
        }
      });
    </script>
    </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <style>
        .panel-primary {
             background-color:{{myColorPanel}};
        }
    </style>
  <div class="panel-primary"><h3>{{name}} ,dynamic Color Change By Angularjs</h3></div>
    <button ng-click="colorChange('red')">Red</button>
    <button ng-click="colorChange('blue')">Blue</button>
    <button ng-click="colorChange('pink')">Pink</button>
    <button ng-click="colorChange('yellow')">Yellow</button>
    
  </body>
  </html>
```

Hope That Was Help you..

Comment: Thank you for the effort dude but still the same with mine and didn't work which i don't really know why.

Answer (score 0):

ng-class is the best option if you want it to work using AngularJs.
You can check this [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass).Hopefully this will give you the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work.

May be there are other places where background color on `.panel-primary` is being set.

You are using bootstrap, right? Make sure your custom CSS is loaded after bootstrap's CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Put the style tag inside your controller, not in the head tag as follows

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    Background of div is <input ng-model="name">
    <style>
      .p { background-color: {{name}}; }
    </style>
    <div class="p">dddd</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: yes i did.. <body data-ng-cloak="" data-ng-controller="indexController">
    <style>
        .panel-primary {
            background-color:{{myColorPanel}}
        }
    </style></body> (Sample instances)

Comment: Please create a plunker if possible. At the time of creating plunker you may found solution.